# Why is pip not working for me?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Observe how I install wstool with pip, and then still cannot invoke it from the CLI. I put all the various paths there too. Can someone see my error?

```
bash-3.2$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
bash-3.2$ sudo -H python -m pip install -U wstool
Password:
Requirement already up-to-date: wstool in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wstool)
Requirement already up-to-date: vcstools>=0.1.38 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wstool)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from vcstools>=0.1.38->wstool)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->vcstools>=0.1.38->wstool)

bash-3.2$ wstool
bash: wstool: command not found

bash-3.2$ pip install -U pip setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
bash-3.2$ wstool
bash: wstool: command not found
bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
bash-3.2$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
bash-3.2$ which python
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
bash-3.2$ which pip
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip
bash-3.2$
```

#### New Details

```
~ ls /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/wstool
ls: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/wstool: No such file or directory
```

So, is my path wrong? This seems to be what pip installed...

```
ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wstool-0.1.13.dist-info/
total 48
-rw-r--r--  1 pitosalas  admin    76 Jul 18 15:52 DESCRIPTION.rst
-rw-r--r--  1 pitosalas  admin   611 Jul 18 15:52 METADATA
-rw-r--r--  1 pitosalas  admin  1885 Jul 18 15:52 RECORD
-rw-r--r--  1 pitosalas  admin    93 Jul 18 15:52 WHEEL
-rw-r--r--  1 pitosalas  admin   738 Jul 18 15:52 metadata.json
-rw-r--r--  1 pitosalas  admin     7 Jul 18 15:52 top_level.txt
```

Comment: are you running as root? does the user have permission to download pip libraries to the install folder?

Comment: wfm in a roughly equivalent docker container (with `python-pip` installed) as well as in a virtualenv

Comment: @Raphael yes: see the sudo... Is there something wrong with my PYTHONPATH or my regular PATH?

Comment: pip says it's there, but is it really? `ls /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/wstool`

Comment: Aha: `ls /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/wstool` ->
`ls: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/wstool: No such file or directory`!! See updated question above for more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip doesn't maintain a database of installed packages. The directories `*.dist-info` **is** its database. While the directory `wstool-0.1.13.dist-info` exists pip thinks the package is installed.

Remove the `dist-info` directory to make pip forgets about the package and reinstall:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wstool-0.1.13.dist-info
sudo python -m pip install -U wstool
```

Comment: Aha! It worked. Can you help me understand why it worked? And how you figured it out. Just so I can solve it myself next time? Thanks!

Comment: I extended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not really answer your question directly, but I suggest you install [Linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh) and let it build your packages for you. In this case, /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages is the standard packages site, however your Python can't see it somehow. And last thing, you should you python2, pip2 instead of generic python, pip just to to be safe.

Comment: I'm running on a mac

Comment: Then I assume you're using Homebrew. Try this in terminal: export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" . Then try wstool again.

Comment: Path already was: /Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin